# Openfire stun server setup

Tags: ios, xmpp, webrtc, openfire, stun

I am using Openfire on ubuntu(aws). Need to setup stun server for webrtc call. To set up stun, openfire is asking for 2 ips. How to solve this or there is any another way to do so.

[image]

Comment: EC2 supports multiple IP addresses. You'll have to assign a secondary IP address when you launch the EC2 instance and then configure /etc/network files.  See my notes here: https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/wiki/EC2-instance-with-2-IP-addresses

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if OpenFire can be configured to run STUN correctly behind a NATed EC2 env. (How would it know the public IP of the secondary address to advertise back?)  Stuntman has explicit options for doing this.  Feel free to check it out: www.stunprotocol.org